# Need help recovering files from SSD (mistakenly replaced partition table with gparted)

Tags: data-recovery, gparted, testdisk

I had windows installed on an SSD, but mistakenly created a new partition table on it using gparted.

Is there any way to at least recover some of the files?

What I have tried so far, is using testdisk, and the scan returns this

TestDisk 6.14, Data Recovery Utility, July 2013
Christophe GRENIER 
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sda - 256 GB / 238 GiB - CHS 31130 255 63

The harddisk (256 GB / 238 GiB) seems too small! (< 415 GB / 386 GiB)
Check the harddisk size: HD jumpers settings, BIOS detection...

The following partitions can't be recovered:
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors

HPFS - NTFS          16044 163 56 47161 195 27  499896593

HPFS - NTFS          19399  85 15 50516 116 49  499896593

The drive is a 256GB SSD

The only backups of the drive, is a system image created by windows backup, though there are 2-3 files that I woud like to recover as they had not been backed up.

---

edit: after it lists what it can't recover, it goes to this window
 (but it detects the partition as 111 GiB)
when the drive originally has a 100MB partition, and an additional partition (drive C) taking the rest of the space on the drive.

TestDisk 6.14, Data Recovery Utility, July 2013
Christophe GRENIER 
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sda - 256 GB / 238 GiB - CHS 31130 255 63

```
 Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
```

- HPFS - NTFS              0   1  1 14592 254 63  234436482

Structure: Ok.  Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
*=Primary bootable  P=Primary  L=Logical  E=Extended  D=Deleted
Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type, P: list files,
     Enter: to continueubuntu-gnome@ubuntu-gnome:~$ 
NTFS, blocksize=4096, 120 GB / 111 GiB

---

Edit again

A deeper scan shows

Disk /dev/sda - 256 GB / 238 GiB - CHS 31130 255 63

```
 Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
```

HPFS - NTFS              0   1  1 14592 254 63  234436482

HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33    12 223 19     204800 [Data]

HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33 31130 190 36  500113408

> HPFS - NTFS             12 223 20 31130  28  2  499898368

Structure: Ok.  Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
*=Primary bootable  P=Primary  L=Logical  E=Extended  D=Deleted
Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type, P: list files,
     Enter: to continue
NTFS, blocksize=4096, 255 GB / 238 GiB

with the last partition showing the correct size, but I am not sure how to select it or if it is even good.

Comment: Forgot to add,while it is scanning, it does show 1 partition that seems to be the correct size, but it disappears on the next screen.  http://i.imgur.com/j7hy3Ff.jpg

Comment: Also if possible how do I go about imaging the drive before attempting to write anything to it?

Comment: wanted to also add, the drive is detected as this in testdisk              Disk /dev/sda - 256 GB / 238 GiB - Samsung SSD 850 PRO 256GB
     CHS 31130 255 63 - sector size=512

Comment: You may have already solved this, but you can try using [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). I basically did something even worse to my hard drive (it was so bad that TestDisk was picking up ISO files and thinking they were partitions!), and PhotoRec was able to recovery the majority of the stuff I had lost.